# print ===== only if middle number is incremented by more than 1 in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, increment

My input file is under the form:

```
1,1,1
2,1,0
3,1,0
4,1,0
5,1,0
6,1,0
7,1,0
8,1,0
1,3,0
2,3,0
3,3,0
4,3,0
5,3,0
6,3,1
7,3,1
8,3,0
1,4,0
2,4,1
3,4,0
4,4,0
5,4,0
6,4,0
7,4,0
8,4,1
1,5,1
2,5,0
3,5,0
4,5,0
5,5,0
6,5,0
7,5,1
8,5,1
```

I am reading this file and storing it into a list of strings as follows, then I am splitting each line by the comma. The number in the middle is incremented after 8 lines and I would like to print
=============== only if it is incremented by more than one. My current output is the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFileLineByLineUsingBufferedReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        List<String> mylist= new ArrayList<String>(); 

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "C:\\Users\\mouna\\ownCloud\\Mouna Hammoudi\\dumps\\Python\\dataMachineLearning.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                // read next line
                mylist.add(line); 

                line = reader.readLine();
            }   
            int counter=0; 
            int last=-1; 
            for(String myline: mylist) {
                    String[] splitted = myline.split("\\,"); 
                    System.out.println(splitted[0]+"  "+splitted[1]+"   "+splitted[2]);
                    int num=Integer.parseInt(splitted[1])+1; 
                    counter++;
                    if(counter%8==0 && num!=last-1) {
                        System.out.println("=============================================");
                    }
                    last=num; 
                    if(counter==8) {
                        counter=0; 
                    }
                     
                
                }
                
                
                
                
            
            
            
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
 1  1   1
    2  1   0
    3  1   0
    4  1   0
    5  1   0
    6  1   0
    7  1   0
    8  1   0
    =============================================
    1  3   0
    2  3   0
    3  3   0
    4  3   0
    5  3   0
    6  3   1
    7  3   1
    8  3   0
    =============================================
    1  4   0
    2  4   1
    3  4   0
    4  4   0
    5  4   0
    6  4   0
    7  4   0
    8  4   1
    =============================================
    1  5   1
    2  5   0
    3  5   0
    4  5   0
    5  5   0
    6  5   0
    7  5   1
    8  5   1
```

This is incorrect as I would only like to print ====================== if the middle number is incremented by more than 1. The correct output should be the following:

```
1  1   1
2  1   0
3  1   0
4  1   0
5  1   0
6  1   0
7  1   0
8  1   0
=============================================
1  3   0
2  3   0
3  3   0
4  3   0
5  3   0
6  3   1
7  3   1
8  3   0
1  4   0
2  4   1
3  4   0
4  4   0
5  4   0
6  4   0
7  4   0
8  4   1
1  5   1
2  5   0
3  5   0
4  5   0
5  5   0
6  5   0
7  5   1
8  5   1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Store the middle number from current iteration in a separate variable. In the next iteration, compare it with this value to check for greater than 1 case.

Comment: Note that you can replace your whole "read-the-file"-loop by just `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("myFile.txt"));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right path and you just had the wrong comparetion in your `if` statement. Also I did some tweaks in your code to simplify it a little bit.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\mouna\\ownCloud\\Mouna Hammoudi\\dumps\\Python\\dataMachineLearning.txt"));
        int last = 0;
        for(String myLine : list) {
            String[] array = myLine.split(",");
            int counter = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
            if(counter == 1 && num > last+1) {
                System.out.println("======");
            }
            System.out.println(array[0]+"  "+array[1]+"  "+array[2]);
            last = num;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've kept your code as is, only replaced the check with the check for the difference in middle number. I've left your old check as a commented line and can be added to the check for and conditions if required. From your question, I only got that the dashed line should only be printed if difference is more than 1, so I took out your check. Here is the modified code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFileLineByLineUsingBufferedReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        List<String> mylist= new ArrayList<String>(); 
        int prevNo = 0;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "C:\\Users\\Admin.MSI\\eclipse-workspace\\Mouna\\dataMachineLearning.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                // read next line
                mylist.add(line); 

                line = reader.readLine();
            }   
            int counter=0; 
            int last=-1; 
            for(String myline: mylist) {
                    String[] splitted = myline.split("\\,"); 
                    
                    int num=Integer.parseInt(splitted[1])+1; 
                    counter++;
                    //if(counter%8==0 && num!=last-1 && Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]) - tempa) > 1 ) {
                    if(Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]) - prevNo) > 1 ) {
                        
                        System.out.println("=============================================");
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println(splitted[0]+"  "+splitted[1]+"   "+splitted[2]);
                    last=num; 
                    if(counter==8) {
                        counter=0; 
                    }
                    prevNo = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
                }                
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the previous middle number in an `Integer`, since primitive `int` does not support `null` values. We use `null` to check whether we are evaluating the first line.

The comparison `middle-1>prev ? LINE +"\n" + currentLine : currentLine` checks whether the middle number subtracted by 1 is bigger than the previous middle number. If it is, we print the equal sign line (constant `LINE`) plus the current line, otherwise we simply print the current line.

In your previous code, you were looping twice, which greatly reduces efficiency. One loop is possible, and is probably the most compact and efficient solution, as demonstrated below:

```
private static final String LINE =  "=============================================";
public static void process(File file) {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
        String currentLine;
        Integer prev = null;
        int linesRead = 0;
        while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int middle = Integer.parseInt(currentLine.split(",")[1]);
            linesRead++;
            if(prev==null) {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }else {
                System.out.println(middle-1>prev && linesReader%8==0 ? LINE +"\n" + currentLine : currentLine);
            }
            prev=middle;
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1,1,1
2,1,0
3,1,0
4,1,0
5,1,0
6,1,0
7,1,0
8,1,0
=============================================
1,3,0
2,3,0
3,3,0
4,3,0
5,3,0
6,3,1
7,3,1
8,3,0
1,4,0
2,4,1
3,4,0
4,4,0
5,4,0
6,4,0
7,4,0
8,4,1
1,5,1
2,5,0
3,5,0
4,5,0
5,5,0
6,5,0
7,5,1
8,5,1
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is, get the current line `splitted[1]` value and the next line `splitted[1]` value. If the difference is `greater` then `1` then `print("===========")`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
    
public class ReadFileLineByLineUsingBufferedReader {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        List<String> mylist= new ArrayList<String>(); 
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\mouna\\ownCloud\\Mouna Hammoudi\\dumps\\Python\\dataMachineLearning.txt"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                mylist.add(line); 
                line = reader.readLine();
            }    
            int last = -1; 
            for(int i = 0; i < mylist.size() - 1; i++) {
                    String[] split_current = mylist.get(i).split("\\,"); 
                    String[] split_next = mylist.get(i + 1).split("\\,"); 
                    System.out.println(split_current[0]+"  "+split_current[1]+"   "+split_current[2]);
                    int num_current = Integer.parseInt(split_current[1]);
                    int num_next = Integer.parseInt(split_next[1]);
                    if(num_next - num_current > 1){
                        System.out.println("=============================================");
                    }
                }    
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.split("\\,")` - the two backslashes are not required.

Comment: Yes it's not required as `","` is not a [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special) like `"."` in _regex_. thanks :)